# Do I have to claim variables as global to use them outside of a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

Seems that this is the only way I figured out how to be able to pull only the variables out of a class - def in a different class without having all the prints and functions in the class I want to call the variables from. Am I right or is there another easier way?

```
class MessageType:
    def process_msg1(self,data)
        item1 = []
        item2 = []
        item3 = []

        item1.append(float(stuff)*stuff)
        item2.append(float(stuff)*stuff)
        item2.append(float(stuff)*stuff)
        print('printing and plotting stuff')

        return(array(item1), array(item2), array(item3))

class PrintMSG(MessageType):
    def process_msg1(self, data):
        (i1, i2, i3) = messagetype.process_msg1(data)
        print('printing plus plotting using variables from class Message')

#processing piece
keep_asking = True
while keep_asking:
    command_type = input("What message type do you want to look at?")
    if command_type == 'msg type1':
        msg = MessageType()
        print_msg = PrintMSG()
        messagetype.process_msg1(self,data)
        print_msg.process_msg1(data)
    elif:
        print('other stuff')
    wannalook = input('Want to look at another message or no?')
    if not wannalook.startswith('y'):
        keep_asking = False
```

The issue I'm having is that I have a project where I need to call variables from other classes inside other classes. I have several other classes with global variables but my issue is `(i1, i2, i3) = messagetype.process_msg1(data)` runs the entire class -def again instead of just calling for the array variables. Is there a way to call them if under the `#processing piece` I already call that class -def?

Reference to previous question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548763/create-an-interactive-command-loop-using-inheritance-python34/34548978?noredirect=1#comment56844120_34548978)!

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask. A code sample would help. Why are you trying to "pull out" something from a class in the first place?

Comment: Please click the link given in my question...the sample code is there..I'm trying to use variables from one class that have calculations that I need in other classes.

Comment: There's a ton of stuff there and it's entirely ambiguous what precisely you're referring to. Update your question with a self-explanatory code sample, ***please.***

Comment: sorry...too early in the morning. Please give me my points back.

Comment: It seems to me you're simply not using OOP correctly. The variables should probably become properties of the object, from where you can access them "from outside" at any time.

Comment: I'm fairly new to python. can you give an example?

Comment: Please fix your formatting.  It looks like everything from `#processing piece` should be indented 8 spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes should be self-contained units of code and data.  Having several classes with several global variables indicates you are almost certainly doing something wrong.

Class data that should last longer than a single method call, whether to be used internally later or to be exposed to other code, should be saved to `self`.  So your `item1`, `item2`, and `item3` should be initialized in the `__init__` method and then `process_msg1` should update them without initializing them.  Something like this:

```
class MessageType:

    def __init__(self):
        self.item1 = []
        self.item2 = []
        self.item3 = []

    def process_msg1(self, data)
        self.item1.append(float(stuff) * stuff)
        self.item2.append(float(stuff) * stuff)
        self.item2.append(float(stuff) * stuff)
        print('printing and plotting stuff')
        return(array(self.item1), array(self.item2), array(self.item3))
```

Then, once you have created an instance (`message_type = MessageType()`) and called the `process_msg1` method (`message_type.process_msg1(1.0, 2.3, 3.14159)`) other code can access it as `message_type.item1`, etc.).

Comment: The 'stuff' actually comes from fields in a csv file. I tried using messagetype.item1 but then am told that item1 is not defined.

Comment: `item1` was not defined because you didn't prefix it with `self.` -- that means it was a local variable and was destroyed as soon as the `MessageType.process_msg1` method finished executing.